# ASP.NET MVC C# : passing view data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

View data not passing to controller. Please note I am using Entity Framework.
Trying to set the values of the Jobcard so that I can save them, but the fields are not binding to the model. Please any help would be appreciated in helping me solve this issue.

View Cshtml

```
@model Amax.Models.Jobcard

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveJobcard", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
}

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success type="submit" id="submit" value="Create Jobcard" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveJobcard", "Home" , FormMethod.Post)'" />
```

HomeController

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveJobcard(Jobcard Jobcard)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

DBModel

```
namespace Amax.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Jobcard
    {
        public long JCId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> ClientId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> ContactId { get; set; }
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string VatNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> SLA { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TofOrder { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TofCompletion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> ClientSigId { get; set; }
        public string CSignature { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ClientSigDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> USigId { get; set; }
        public string USignature { get; set; }
        public string USigDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusId { get; set; }

        public List<JobCardItem> Item { get; set; }
    }
    //public JobCardItem()
    //{
    //    Item = new List<JobCardItem>();
    //}
}
```

View Model

```
namespace Amax.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Jobcard Jobcard { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public JobCardItem JobCardItem { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public User Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Jobcard Object empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CeF7.png)

[Fields Populated on form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cuvk.png)
[Form Submit Network tab details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWSMG.png)

Adding in the full view html code

````
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveJobcard", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="JobCard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Company Name :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="ClientId" value="ClientId">
                                @{
                                    <option value="0">
                                        Please Select
                                    </option>
                                    var Clients = ((Amax.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetClients();
                                    foreach (var client in Clients)
                                    {
                                        <option onclick="@Url.Action("GetContacts", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = @client.ClientId }));" value="@client.ClientId">
                                            @client.ClientName
                                        </option>
                                    }

                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Contact No :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ContactNo" name="ContactNo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Vat No :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VatNo" name="VatNo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Contact Person :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="ContactId" name="ContactId">
                                <option value="0">
                                    Please Select
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">SLA :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Address :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Address" name="Address" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">Time & Date of Order :</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><input type="date" /> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">Time & Date of Completion :</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><input type="date" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Assigned Person :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="assigned" name="assigned">
                                @{
                                    <option value="0">
                                        Please Select
                                    </option>
                                    var Users = ((Amax.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetUsers();
                                    foreach (var user in Users)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@user.UserId">
                                            @user.UserName @user.Surname
                                        </option>
                                    }

                                }

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Status :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="StatusId" name="StatusId">
                                @{
                                    <option value="0">
                                        Please Select
                                    </option>
                                    var Status = ((Amax.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetStatus();
                                    foreach (var status in Status)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@status.Id">
                                            @status.Status1
                                        </option>
                                    }

                                }

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success type="submit" id="submit" value="Create Jobcard" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SaveJobcard", "Home" , FormMethod.Post)'" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">#</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-8"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">Description</label></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">Unit Price</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"> <label class="label" style="color:black;">Total</label></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="JobItems">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="btnAdd"> + </button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="remove_1"> - </button></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">Total</div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><label id="Jc_total">R 0.00</label></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            Terms:<br />
                            1. All equipment remains the property of AMAX until fully paid and client acknowledges that AMAX reserves the right to remove the equipment in the absence of payment.<br />
                            Client acknowledges that the equipment belongs to AMAX until fully paid and that the client shall not, under any circumstances, alienate, tarnish, destroy or erode the equipment.<br />
                            Client shall also ensure reasonable use of the equipment and shall ensure that the equipment is not exposed to negative elements which could alienate, tarnish, destroy or erode the goods.<br />
                            2. Customer agrees that AMAX may remove equipment if not paid within 7 working days of job completion.<br />
                            3. Customer will allow AMAX access to installation site to remove equipment that is unpaid.<br />
                            4. All Equipment carries a 1 year manufacturer’s guarantee.<br />
                            5. The Customer Agrees that the job has been done to his or her satisfaction
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                            <div class="row">
                                <dic class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    Banking Details: Bank: Acc Name: Acc No: Branch Code: Type:
                                    FNB Amax Electronics 623402 97028 251045 Cheque
                                    Proof of payment: Mail accounts@amaxelectronics.co.za Fax: 012 543 2394
                                    Ref: JN Number
                                </dic>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pull-right">

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("PDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" name="Styles" id="Styles" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ExportData" id="ExportData" />
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Generate PDF" />
                        }
                        @*<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" onclick="@Url.Action("PDF", "Home")">Generate PDF</button>*@
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the form values to the parameter in your controller

```
public ActionResult SaveJobcard([FromForm]Jobcard jobcard)
```

Comment: Does not seem to solve the issue as the values came thru once and now back to null no matter the input.

Comment: How do you mean once and then null? Do you mean resubmitting the form

Comment: I am trying to figure out what happened, so the adjustement to the code was made to bind the form with the `[FromForm]` had to update the AspNetCore.Mvc
After that tested the run and added a breakpoint to the function. On hover of the Jobcard object I could see the email typed into the field. Stopped the project reran the solution and tried to post new data to the function... No changes in property values can be seen.

Comment: So the second time you looked at the breakpoint the value of job card was null? Have you checked the network tab to see the format of the payload being posted? Other option is to add logging to the controller to see what is happening

Comment: Yes no values are coming thru from this point on, I am unsure as to what is causing this issue, a reference error? or a conflict between my viewmodel and model . I have no idea why this is happening and I have tried a few solution using google but to no avail. Your answer got me the closest to passing the data thru.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to the problem was that one has to add form Html tags to wrap inside the
html you want to submit

Wrong

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveJobcard", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="JobCard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Company Name :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="ClientId" value="ClientId">
                                @{
                                    <option value="0">
                                        Please Select
                                    </option>
                                    var Clients = ((Amax.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetClients();
                                    foreach (var client in Clients)
                                    {
                                        <option onclick="@Url.Action("GetContacts", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = @client.ClientId }));" value="@client.ClientId">
                                            @client.ClientName
                                        </option>
                                    }

                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Works Perfect

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveJobcard", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <form>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="JobCard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="label" style="color:black;">Company Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="ClientId" value="ClientId">
                                @{
                                    <option value="0">
                                        Please Select
                                    </option>
                                    var Clients = ((Amax.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetClients();
                                    foreach (var client in Clients)
                                    {
                                        <option onclick="@Url.Action("GetContacts", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = @client.ClientId }));" value="@client.ClientId">
                                            @client.ClientName
                                        </option>
                                    }

                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    }
```